# Gitlab generate a zip with chosen folders

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci

In Gitlab, is there a way with CI/CD or another trick to generate a .zip package with chosen folders  after each commit? A script to use in CI/CD ?

I know we can download a whole repository with the button "download source code" but I need to create a package .zip with only some folders of the repository.

Thanks :).

Answer (score 2):

You can either generate a artifact or publish the file as [a generic package](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/packages/generic_packages/#publish-a-generic-package-by-using-cicd).

### Artifact

```
empaquetar:
  image: alpine
  before_script:
    - apk add --update zip
  script:
    - zip -r content.zip folder1 folder2
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - content.zip
    when: on_success
```

### Package

```
empaquetar:
  image: alpine
  before_script:
    - apk add --update zip curl
  script:
    - zip -r content.zip folder1 folder2
    - 'curl 
        --header "JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN"
        --upload-file content.zip
        "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/generic/Content/1.0.0/content.zip"'
```

Where `Content` in `generic/Content/1.0.0` is the package name and `1.0.0` the version.

You can also use [`$CI_COMMIT_TAG`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#list-all-environment-variables) variable as version if the pipeline executes only on tagged branch with a condition like this:

```
empaquetar:
  image: alpine
  script:
    - zip -r content.zip folder1 folder2
    - 'curl 
        --header "JOB-TOKEN: $CI_JOB_TOKEN"
        --upload-file content.zip
        "${CI_API_V4_URL}/projects/${CI_PROJECT_ID}/packages/generic/Content/${CI_COMMIT_TAG}/content.zip"'
  only:
    variables:
      - $CI_COMMIT_TAG =~ /^\d+.\d+.\d+*$/
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your base Docker image (if you use one), you may need to install zip.

After this you can run something like:

```
zip -r archive.zip folder1 folder2 folder3
```

Finally, you need to do something with the achive.zip file (like declaring it as an artifact or uploading it somewhere), otherwise, it will get lost once the job finishes.

Comment: what kind of docker image can I use to have zip installed?

Comment: @bAN I think you are asking the wrong question. Figure out which image you are using and if that image does not have zip, install it using the package manager.